# google charts: vary colors based on names in linechart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

from this http://jsfiddle.net/QHJA6/161/ fiddle im tryin to display different colors based on different names say for

```
'FOO' blue 
'BAR' yellow
'BAZ' green
...
```

and the values might vary for them ... 
SO home my data looks is

```
[1,'FOO', 5]
[2,'BAR', 10]
[3,'BAZ', 7]
....
....
```

thus the colors will follow the first value, but the value to plot will be different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That jsfiddle example is obsolete, as the Visualization API now allows specifying colors for individual columns using the "style" column role, which is much simpler.  Given a DataTable with 3 columns (x-value, category, y-value), you can create a map of values to colors and use a DataView to set the column colors:

```
var colorMap = {
    FOO: '#0000ff',
    BAR: '#00ff00',
    BAZ: '#ffff00'
};

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 2, {
    type: 'string',
    role: 'style',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        return colorMap[dt.getValue(row, 1)];
    }
}]);
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/aPh8Z/

Comment: Would you mind marking this answer as accepted then, to help other users with similar issues find it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `colors` in your options.

Try:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(view, {
            legend: 'none',
            isStacked: true,
            height: 300,
            width: 800,
            colors:['blue','yellow','green'] //ADD THIS
        });
```

And then the each column will have the color you have specified.

For example here first column will be blue,second will be yellow and so on

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QHJA6/163/)

Comment: ok this is how i achieved..http://jsfiddle.net/QHJA6/168/ .. but is there a way to associate one color unique to one name, and thus it doesn't repeat to other name, means FOO=YELLOW, and BLUE can't be associated to any other names...